# how can I transfer data more efficiently on python asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, ftp, python-asyncio

In my FTP implementation, I want to transfer a big file more efficiently, but in asyncio, `loop.send` or `transport.write` will set psh standard on tcp flags, it wont buffer data. So, is there a better solution in this situation? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OydmJ.png)

Comment: You'll have to show us your code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The push bit, with length 12, implies that you are sending the kernel a dozen bytes at a time. That is, you are doing a chapter-two write(2) kernel call with a tiny buffer. It sounds like you would rather be doing buffered writes in userspace, and only calling into the kernel once the buffer has filled up with a few kilobytes.